# How to make mini table of contents unbolded

Tags: table-of-contents, books, minitoc, section-titles

The standard appearance of `\usepackage{minitoc}` is with **bold** letters for each of the sections/subsections of a chapter. How would I go about making a mini table of contents with unbolded letters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `\dominitoc` and `\minitoc` commands, you can redefine the commands `\mtcfont` (applied to whole minitoc), `\mtcSfont` (applied to section listings), `\mtcSSfont` (applied to subsections), etc. I think the default definition is `\small\bfseries` so you can leave out `\bfseries`, or make any other changes you'd like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\renewcommand{\mtcfont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\mtcSSfont}{\small}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\faketableofcontents

\chapter{My chapter}

\minitoc

\section{My first section}

\subsection{My first subsection}

\section{My second section}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\minitoc

\section{This section}

\end{document}
```

For more, see the [minitoc documentation](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/contents/minitoc.pdf), page 7.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. 

A last question: the word CONTENTS still appears in bold. How can I change this to normal font?

Comment: You can do a similar redefinition of the `\mtifont` command. The default is `\large\bfseries` so you could so `\renewcommand{\mtifont}{\large}`. See the documentation, linked above, page 35.

Comment: Thank you very much!